# ¿Cómo poner un valor como subindice?

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe como este:

```
 Value  marker  groups
   4    Meta R5 1
   5    Meta R5 1
   5    Meta R5 1
   5    Meta R5 1
   3    Meta R5 1
   6    Meta R5 1
   6    Meta R5 1
   5    Meta R5 1
   5    Meta R5 1
   6    Meta R5 1
   3    Meta R5 1
   6    Meta R5 1
   6    Meta R5 1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   4    FEV1    1
   5    FEV1    1
   5    FEV1    1
   5    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
   6    FEV1    1
```

y me gustaría poder tener el valor de FEV1 con el 1 como subindice para la columna marker.
Para ello he utilizado la siguiente función:

```
   FEV <- bquote(FEV[1])
   comparation1$marker <-gsub("FEV1",FEV,comparation1$marker)
```

Y me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
   Warning message:
    In gsub("FEV1", FEV, comparation1$marker) :
     argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Me sustituye el valor de FEV1 por [. Me gustaría saber como poder poner el 1 como subindice con el objetivo de realizar posteriormente esta gráfica:

```
bp <- ggbarplot(
  comparation1, x = "marker", y = "Value", fill = "marker", add = "mean_sd",
  position = position_dodge(0.8)
)

grouped <- grouped %>%
  add_xy_position(x = "marker", fun = "mean_sd", dodge = 0.8)

bp +   my_theme()+
  stat_pvalue_manual(grouped,
                 label = "p.adj.signif", 
                 tip.length = 0.1,
                 label.size = 15,
                 bracket.nudge.y = -0.3,
                 hide.ns = TRUE, 
                 y.position = 8, 
                 step.increase = 0.03) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, 2),
                 limits = c(0, 10))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Meta R5" = "#FF6666", "FEV1" = "orange"))+
  labs(x = "", y="")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=1,byrow=FALSE))
```

Obteniendo una gráfica como esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la que el nombre del eje X (introducido en la imagen como ejemplo) sería lo que querría como etiqueta de la primera columna.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo se vería el resultado que quieres obtener?

Comment: Hola @mpaladino he actualizado la pregunta añadiendo una imagen de la figura que me gustaría obtener. El resultado que quiero obtener sería el caracter FEV normal y un 1 como subindice

Comment: Si es para el gráfico nada más los más directo sería pasar el nombre del eje x como argumento para `labs`. Algo así como `labs(x = bquote(FEV[1])` y ya. Poner una expresión sin evaluar en un columna me parece complicado.

Comment: Perdona @mpaladino, me expliqué mal. No quiero esa expresión para el título del eje x sino como etiqueta de la primera columna.

Comment: Ya lo he sacado @mpaladino la solución sería esta scale_x_discrete(labels=c(bquote(FEV[1]), "Meta R5"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que no se puede cambiar el dataframe del que parte el gráfico, lo suyo es cambiar la etiqueta del nombre de cada barra para ello he utilizado esto:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels=c(bquote(FEV[1]), "Meta R5"))
```